# TypeError when trying to create events in Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

First Timer here! Attemtping to create Google Calendar events from spreadsheet data.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null (line 149, file "Code")

Attempted to debug with no luck:

```
  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

    var shift = signups [x];

    var startDate = shift [0];
    var endDate = shift [1];
    var attendee = shift [2];

   eventCal.createEvent(attendee,startDate,endDate);
 }
```

Comment: Please post your more of your code. eventCal is undefined you net to figure why.

Comment: **/
  for   (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
  
    var shift = signups [x];
    
    var startDate = shift [0];
    var endDate = shift [1];
    var attendee = shift [2];
    
    eventCal.createEvent (attendee, startDate, endDate); 
  }

Comment: Please post it in the question

Comment: Please, post *all* of the code. Obviously, `eventCal` variable has a value of `null`, but the exact reason is unknown until we see the rest of your code